# Set Cpp class members as columns in sqlite DB

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a requirement to have the class members as DB (sqlite) columns and also define relationships using primary and foreign keys. How can we achieve this? Should we define the relationship ourselves while creating the tables or is there any libraries/extensions I can use.

```
class A
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
}

class B
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    int AID;
}

class C
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    int BID;
}
```

For the above class structure, I need to create DB tables for each classes and each table should have the members as the columns. In each table, Member variable ID of respective classes should be primary key for each DB and AID (ID of class A) should be foreign key in class B and BID (ID of class B) should be foreign key in class C.

Is there any library/extension which I can use to keep the relationships between the classes or it should be handled manually in code.?

I have found some extensions for C#.Net but I'd love if something similar is available for C++.

http://www.dsibinski.pl/2017/05/sqlite-net-extensions-one-to-many-relationships/

Comment: This is super unclear. Please provide a [mcve]. I assume you're talking about having a `sqlTable` class that has some members, and those members should be the columns in the table, but more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I were, I would have created XSD or XML schema from my classes and create databases using that schema!. That would work!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way to do that which is creating the tables manually than using additional libraries. There is another alternative library which is good and can help in achieve the same.

https://github.com/paulftw/hiberlite

https://code.google.com/archive/p/hiberlite/